# Chave do JSON com Espaçamento, "." e letra Maiuscula

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, aplicação-web

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá gente, gostaria de saber como consigo pegar os valores de HP, Sp. Attack e Sp. Defense no Javascript??
os valores abaixo funcionam mas o citados não =[

```
  console.log(pokedata[id].base.Attack);
  console.log(pokedata[id].base.Defense);
  console.log(pokedata[id].base.Speed);
```

Comment: Considere colar o código ao invés de postar o print do JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimenta usar: `pokedata[id].base["Sp. Attack"]` e de maneira igual para os outros atributos.
Se perceberes inglês lê esta pergunta no Stack Overflow inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311361/accessing-json-object-keys-having-spaces

Comment: obrigado joao!! eu já tinha testado esse metodo e não estava funcionando mas agora que eu copiei e colei sua reposta funcionou!!. vai entender rsrs